# Yahoo finance - error trying to download option chain with r - Quantmod

Tags: r, finance, quantmod, yahoo

Started getting the following error message while downloading the option chain - it was working fine until few days ago...

```r
uOUT.OPT <- getOptionChain("TSLA","2024")
```

> Error in Exp/86400 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> In addition: Warning message:
> In open.connection(con, "rb") :
> cannot open URL 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/options/TSLA': HTTP status was '401 Unauthorized'

... also getting the below when trying to download the joshuaulrich fix...any other fix available?

> remotes::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod@407-getoptionchain")
> Downloading GitHub repo joshuaulrich/quantmod@407-getoptionchain
> Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  :
> cannot open URL 'https://api.github.com/repos/joshuaulrich/quantmod/tarball/407-getoptionchain'

Comment: Just use `remotes::install_github("joshuaulrich/quantmod")` The "@407-getoptionchain" was probably just a working branch that was deleted after the code was merged into the main branch.

Comment: Thanks - it worked! Now I am getting the following error message though:  "Error in getOptionChain.yahoo(Symbols = "TSLA", Exp = "2024") : 
  Unable to obtain yahoo crumb. If this is being called from a GDPR country, Yahoo requires GDPR consent, which cannot be scripted